# Erro Código Google Maps API

Tags: javascript

Eu estou reconstruindo meu sistema php, mas esta dando um erro, onde os multiplos ponteiros não estão aparecendo e eu não estou conseguindo achar o erro, pois o mapa esta sendo exibido, eu creio que o erro esta no laço FOR mas eu não estou conseguindo localizar o erro, alguem me ajudaria ?

```
        var locations = [];
        locations.push ( {name:"Las Vegas", latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(36.255123, -115.2383485)} );
        locations.push ( {name:"California", latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(36.778261, -119.4179324)} );
        locations.push ( {name:"New York", latlng: new    google.maps.LatLng(40.7143528, -74.00597309999)} );

        for(var i=0;i<locations.length;i++){

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:locations[i].latlng, map:map, title:locations[i].name});

        }
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

O problema ao que parece está na sua variável map. Veja se esse exemplo ajuda

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, vou analisar o código.